Can you use the beta-binomial distribution instead of MCMC?
So, I have a project to test the hypothesis that a marketing campaign with a new art generates more purchases than the old one, I have 2 samples of data, one using the standard ad and one using the new ad. So we have the total number of impressions and the number of purchases. We can estimate this as a $\text{Binomial}(\text{impressions}, \text{purchases} / \text{impressions})$.
So, if we say that:
$$
\begin{align}
&X_{c} \sim \text{Binomial}(I_{c},\theta_{c})\\
&X_{t} \sim \text{Binomial}(I_{t},\theta_{t})
\end{align}
$$
and we use a $\theta \sim \text{Beta}(1,1)$ as a prior we can get the respective posterior for the test and the control. So, my question is, can i use the beta-binomial distribution as a analytic way to do the hypothesis test? Or do I have to use a MonteCarlo Markov Chain simulation and do it the usual way?
My reasoning was that, given the data, we can calculate the probability of the number of puchases $\tilde{x}$ as
$$
P(\tilde{x}=x \ |X_{t},\theta'_{t})\sim \text{Beta-Bin}(I_t,1+x_t,1+I_t-x_t)
$$
with $\theta'_t$ being the posterior of $f(X_t \ | \ \theta_t)$ and $x_t$ the number of purchases that the test advertisement had. So I could use this to calculate the BayesFactor
$$
BF_{10}=\frac{P(\tilde{x}\geq x_t \ | X_t ,\theta_t')}{P(\tilde{x}\geq x_t \ | X_c ,\theta_c')}
$$
instead of using the usual MCMC simulation and comparing the results.
Obs: I had this posted on the Math stack but after being told about this one i felt it would be a better fit.

Why would you wanna avoid mc?

@Ggjj11 Basically i want to run this in a google spreadsheet, so mc simulation is not that feasible

Yes - if the model is simple enough to calculate the posterior analytically, there is no reason you can't do that instead of sampling the posterior. In practice, this is rarely the case, hence MCMC, but theoretically the analytical solution should always give accurate possible answer.

This means that any Beta-Binomial model could just use the Beta-Bin distribution and calculate it analytically?

I don't think so exactly. In your example the prior is technically a beta distribution, but Beta(1,1) is really equivalent to uniform(0,1), which really simplifies the math if you're doing it analytically. If you're using a more complex beta for a prior, I think the average likelihood function (denominator in Bayes Theorem) starts to become challenging to calculate analytically.

Oh, i see. The problem is that the CDF has the Hypergeometric function and sometimes isnt easy to calculate analitically, right? But python has already a function in scipy that can solve the CDF of the betabin, thats why i wanted to use this approach. That said, thank you very much for the answer, it was very direct and helpful!
